# How to fix matplotlib overlapping graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib

i want to plot the data that i have scraped over the internet using matplotlib.. for the sake of simplicity here is the pseudocode

```
<IMPORTS HERE>

for i in a_list:
    df = <SOME DATAF HERE>
    plt.plot(df)
    plt.title(<ENTER TITLE HERE>)
    plt.savefig(<ENTER FILENAME HERE>)
```

i am expecting that the graphs that will be generated  are by its own but when i ran the code, the data/graph from the first iteration of the loop was carried over to the second iteration, and the data/graph from the second and first iteration of the loop was carried over to the third iteration.

hence the result is as follows

[image]

[image]

[image]

is there any way to fix this?

thank you

Comment: `plt.savefig()` doesn't erase the existing plot.  You can erase it explicitly using `plt.clf()`.  Note that `plt.show()` shows the plot and then erases it.

Comment: ahhh thank you for this.. i didnt know that plt.savefig() doesn't erase the existing plot since it doesnt say in the matplotlib manual..